# Import list from powershell to money field

Tags: list, powershell

If I tried to import from powershell to sharepoint field it adds me two 00 to the values. How to import a fields in this sequention 000,00
I have got a MS SQL view with this form 000,00 but when I import to list it shows me 00000,00, i don't know why powershell don't see the comma.

The code of powershel is:

```
$new["Test Field1"] = $i.TestField1
$new["Test Field2"] = $i.xTestField2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **[Double]::Parse("xxx")**

```
$item["currencyfield"] = [Double]::Parse("123.48");
$item.Update();
```

You can find a complete guide about powershell and list s fields here:

[getting-and-setting-fields Powershell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx)

Comment: But i don't do it by C#, I do it by powershell

Comment: I edited the link